# How do languages handle bitwise flags?

Tags: syntax, types, type-inference

In most languages, `enum` types intersect with number types, implicitly converting between them so you can do `SomeEnum.VariantA | SomeEnum.VariantB` to work with flags. In C# `enum`s are numbers with custom methods, getters and setters and built-ins such as `HasFlag()`. In GDScript `enum`s are numbers without custom methods etc. In Rust, IIRC there's a separate `bitflags` crate with type-safe flags.

How do other languages facilitate working with bitwise flags?

For example:

- Is there a language that infers the type from where a variant comes (based on Swift (`let x: Enum = .variant`) or Haxe), a feature from which flags can be wrote faster? Of course as I know neither Swift nor Haxe support flags enums: Haxe uses `enum`s for algebraic data types.
- Is there a language that is type-safe, i.e., that does not allow to assign a number to a flags typed property without explicit conversion?

Comment: Apologies I have [metad your question](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/409/what-do-we-think-of-this-style-of-how-is-x-implemented-in-your-language-questi) as I think it raises some interesting questions.

Answer (score 5):

### C++

Famously, C++ supports bit flags in a library, [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). This is often used in conjunction with an enumerated type:

```cpp
enum {
    FLAG_1,
    FLAG_2,
    FLAG_3,
    FLAG_COUNT // Not used as an actual flag
};

std::bitset<FLAG_COUNT> flags; // This is how you represent flags.

// This is how you use them.
flags[FLAG_3] = true;
if (flags[FLAG_2]) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

> Of course as I know neither Swift nor Haxe support flags enums: Haxe uses enums for algebraic data types.

Swift has `OptionSet`.

`OptionSet`, like the standard hash-based `Set<T>`, inherits from the `SetAlgebra` protocol. However, its element type is itself, and you get a lot of the conformances for free.

Consider this short program, which demonstrates most of the common operations:

```swift
// Let's define such a type.
struct MyOptions: OptionSet {
  var rawValue: Int

  // ...yep, that's it.

  // Presumably you also want something like these:
  static let foo = MyOptions(rawValue: 1 << 0)
  static let bar = MyOptions(rawValue: 1 << 1)
  static let baz = MyOptions(rawValue: 1 << 2)
}

// Create two values: one that's just foo, and one that's both foo and bar
let first: MyOptions = .foo
let second: MyOptions = [.foo, .bar]

// Check what flags they have in common
print(first.intersection(second)) // first & second in C
// Remove first from second
print(second.subtracting(first)) // second & ~first in C
// Test for membership
if second.contains(first) { // second & first == first in C
  print("\(first) is in \(second)!")
}
// Merge it with .baz
print(first.union(.baz)) // first | baz in C
```

For further reading, see the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset-swift.protocol.

Comment: Looking here it seems Swift is powerful.

Answer (score 2):

In Tuplet, `enum`s are sum types, whereas the "combinable" flag-like options use `flags`. Here is an example:

```
FlagRegister /* 6502 "P" flags register */ = [flags(u8)] {
  carry, // least significant bit
  zero, // next bit
  disable_interrupts,
  decimal,
  b_flag,
  // bit 5 is always 1
  [private] bit5 always true, // a `FlagRegister` value must have bit5 == 1, or it fails at construction
  // alternatively, to just ignore it
  [private] bit5 = true,
  overflow,
  negative,
} // The compiler checks that there are 8 bits

a: FlagRegister = 2b0010_0100
b = FlagRegister(carry, decimal) // same as 2b0010_1001
c = a | b // carry, decimal, disable_interrupts(, bit5)
// + and | do the same thing
d = a + FlagRegister.b_flag // disable_interrupts, b_flag(, bit5)
e = a - FlagRegister.disable_interrupts // (bit5)
f = b :~ FlagRegister.disable_interrupts // toggle: carry, decimal, disable_interrupts(, bit5)
g = a :~ FlagRegister.disable_interrupts // (bit5)
h = b & FlagRegister(carry) // carry(, bit5)
i = a & FlagRegister.carry // (bit5)

core::assert(c.decimal) // compile time assertion
core::assert(!c.negative)
core::assert(std::reflect::compile { _: FlagRegister = 0 }.is_empty) // fails because bit5 is false

[runtime] y: u8 = 0
z = FlagRegister(d) // fails at runtime if the compiler can't statically know that bit5 is true
```

assuming `Q` is a type implementing `Integer`, `T` is a type implementing `Bitwise(Q)`, `F = [flags(T)] { a, b, ... }`, `q` of type `Q`, and `x`, `y` of type `F` these are all the supported operations:

- `x.value` and its alias `@x` gets the integer representation
- `x | y` and its aliases `x + y` and `x.or(y)` is `F(@x | @y)`
- `x & y` and its alias `x.and(y)` is `F(@x & @y)`
- `x - y` and its alias `x.without(y)` is `F(@x & ~@y)`
- `x :~ y` and its alias `x.toggle(y)` is `F(@x ^ @y)`
- `x.a`, `x.b`, etc
- `x(q)` and its alias `x.at(q)` gets the `q`-th bit (0 is the lowest bit)
- `~x` and its alias `x.negate` is `F(~@x)`

`F` will of course also inherit the operations from its typeclasses, most notably `Show F`, `Read F`, `Formattable F`, `Integer F`, `Sequence(Bool) F`, `Bitwise(Q) F`, `FiniteBitwise(Q) T` => `FiniteBitwise(Q) F`.

Answer (score 1):

## VioletScript

My language has a type-safe (i.e. not mixed with number types) numeric `enum`. You can work with flags by adding the reserved `Flags` decorator. It is *not* necessary to specify the value for each variant; you can omit the `= ...` part. It supports custom methods, getters and setters and enum variant inference.

Every variant has an unique number and an unique user-friendly string.

I'd say working with flags is safer and more efficient in VioletScript than working with flags in C#. I don't know of another language with the same characteristics (there is one someone mentioned me that has flags enums, but I forgot the name, though I still bet there are differences).

##### Enum Variant Inference

The language implicitly converts string literals, array initializers and object initializers to `enum`s wherever expected. Even the `undefined` constant too (equivalent to `{}` or `[]`).

You can think of this as similiar to variant inference in Swift or Haxe. I don't know Swift, but in Haxe `enum`s (that keyword) are algebraic data types; in VioletScript they're rather the equivalent of C#, except they're type-safe and also associate an user-friendly string:

VioletScript example:

```
const modifiers: Modifiers = 'someModifier'
const modifiers: Modifiers = ['someModifier', 'anotherModifier']
const modifiers: Modifiers = { someModifier: true }
```

##### Variant Structure

This is about how the `enum` defines the variants.

- Variant has an `enum` static property.

  - Variant has a number (`valueOf()`).
  - Variant has an user-friendly string (`toString()`).

What you assign at the right side of the variant is just a compile-time association:

- If it's a string literal, associates an user-friendly string and let the compiler infer the number.
- If it's a numeric literal, associates a number and let the compiler infer the string.
- If it's a `[str, num]` or `[num, str]` array, associates the specified number and string.

If no initialiser, let the compiler infer the number and string.

##### Number and String Inference

- The `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` constant name is implicitly converted into an user-friendly camel-case string (`screamingSnakeCase`).
- Like in all other languages, the number is inferred based on a counter. *However*, different from C#, it will assign correct flags: for flags the counter will multiply per 2 each increment.

##### Strictness

- Duplicates are not allowed.
- A number in a flags type must be either 1 or power of two.

##### Example

```
[Flags]
enum E {
    X
    Y = 32
    Z = 'zZ'
    W = ['k', 512]

    // custom method
    function f(): void {
        trace(this.valueOf())
    }

    // custom getter
    function get prop(): Number (this.valueOf() + 5)
}

const e: E = ['x', 'k']
assert('x' in e) // has flag 'x'

const e: E = { x: true }

// is not empty
assert(e != {})

const e = e.toggle('x')
```

To clarify:

- `E.X`

  - `E.X.valueOf() == 1`
  - `E.X.toString() == 'x'`
- `E.Y`

  - `E.Y.valueOf() == 32`
  - `E.Y.toString() == 'y'`
- `E.Z`

  - `E.Z.valueOf() == 64`
  - `E.Z.toString() == 'zZ'`
- `E.W`

  - `E.W.valueOf() == 512`
  - `E.W.toString() == 'k'`

##### Basic Syntax

```
'flag' in f
f = f.toggle('flag')
f = f.filter(other)
f = f.include(other)
f = f.exclude(other)

// specify custom number type
[Flags]
enum E wraps BigInt {
}
```